# Unable to login through CAS Single Sign-on using grails

Tags: grails, spring-security, cas

I am using a grails application that has the spring security core and spring security CAS plugins. I have setup a jasig CAS server with a database authentication. So far if I login directly through CAS with the users in the database, it works fine.

The problem I have is when I try to login from the grails application. I successfully get redirected to the CAS page, where after login, I get sent back to my grails app with an error of bad credentials.

In the tomcat logs of the CAS server, I have this trace:

`2015-01-21 10:55:59,182 WARN [org.jasig.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager] - <Cannot find authentication handler that supports http://localhost:8080/myGrailsApp/secure/receptor, which suggests a configuration problem.>`

Below are my settings in grails:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.serverUrlPrefix = 'https://localhost:8443/cas'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.loginUri = '/login'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.proxyReceptorUrl = '/secure/receptor'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.serviceUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/myGrailsApp/j_spring_cas_security_check'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.proxyCallbackUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/myGrailsApp/secure/receptor'
```

This is an existing project with a valid spring security that we've been using for a while, now trying to move it into single sign-on.

What setting am I missing in my CAS server or grails application? I have followed the [default setup for database auth handler](http://jasig.github.io/cas/4.0.x/installation/Maven-Overlay-Installation.html) in setting up my CAS server.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you post your complete config of Spring Security + CAS, please? I'll compare with my config. I'm successfully using Spring Security + CAS in two grails applications. One app in Grails 2.2.5 and another in 2.4.3. My CAS server authenticates against an Active Directory server, but I don't think this fact has some relation with your problem. Looks like it's a configuration you'll have to do in your CAS server.

Comment: It looks like I had no need for the `proxy` urls in the grails config. I removed those and it worked right away. I don't yet understand in depth the CAS server or the client side implementation of the grails plugin and I had assumed those configs were necessary. Thanks for looking into it either way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need to use the CAS proxy feature? Because the CAS error says that the CAS server is not configured to handle proxy callbacks while your CAS client is configured to use proxy (I guess: `proxyReceptorUrl` and `proxyCallbackUrl` properties)

Comment: I assumed those were required from following the config documentation for this specific CAS client. Removed them, and it worked right away. Thank you yet again!